# ¿Cómo puedo extraer tablas que están en formato imagen a una tabla que pueda manipular?

Tags: python-3.x, datatables, archivo, datatable, google-colab

Tengo miles de archivos en formato PDF que no se pueden subrayar, es decir que son imágenes. Dentro de estos archivos hay texto normal y tablas, he estado usando esta herramienta de LayoutParser para poder extraer la información (cabe recalcar que todo lo estoy haciendo en Google Colab), hasta ahora todo bien con el texto, pero a la hora de llegar a las tablas me revuelve toda la información. Busqué que el atributo TableExtractor me podría ayudar, pero al utilizarlo me sale el siguiente error, busqué en internet y encontré que debía actualizar PL, lo hice, pero aún sigue el error, también lo importe (import TableExtractor), alguien me podría ayudar a saber qué atributo debo utilizar por favor:

```
1 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/layoutparser/file_utils.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    224             value = getattr(module, name)
    225         else:
--> 226             raise AttributeError(f"module {self.__name__} has no attribute {name}")
    227 
    228         setattr(self, name, value)

AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute TableExtractor
```

Comment: No olvides agregar a tu pregunta el código que estas utilizando ya que de otra forma es más complicado encontrar una solución. ;)